# MariaDB giving error on specific line when importing dump from MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I was struggling with importing a database from MySQL in production server to MariaDB on my laptop.

The production server version (Centos 6):

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

The local server (Windows10):

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.15-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64), source revision 07aef9f7eb936de2b277f8ae209a1fd72510c011
```

I have created the dump using this command:

```
mysqldump -u root -p  --routines --comments --force --single-transaction --quick interno | gzip -9 > interno.gz
```

Then when I try to import it I get an error like this:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 110: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for 
the right syntax to use near ''centre_exercici');
```

So, the line that contains the error goes like this:

```
SET _SEQ_IMPORTACIO = nextval('centre_exercici');
```

But if I change it to this, the error disappears:

```
SET _SEQ_IMPORTACIO = 123;
```

This is the SQL dump that I'm trying to import:

https://pastebin.com/DK2xvCuW

(I've isolated the error in a smaller file, the original file is 200MB)

So as mentioned, I simply remove the function `nextval('centre_exercici')` and replace it with a regular integer number and voila, it works.

Here is the definition of `nextval` function:

https://pastebin.com/xNarYrAy

Comment: See: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/nextval/ - `NEXTVAL` is part of core syntax in MariaDB 10.3

Comment: Fuck, thanks man!! I have just stumbled upon that when running a `show function nextval` to check its code.

Comment: Okay, again I ran into a similar error with a newer MariaDB and the same dump. Now the issue was using a variable that wasn't declared. Basically it was a procedure that it was not in use anymore and we forgot to delete it.